# Getting latency on VM when creating snapshot of Virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have Vmware and we are taking backup of virtual machines using NetBackup software. When Backup starts it creates snapshot and then takes backup. During snapshot creation it freezes vmdk for certain time, due to this users are getting disconnection error on application running on VM.

As the server uses time is 24x7 so there is no specific time where users are not connected with application and we can run backup at that time.

Is there any option on VMware so that this issue can be resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can minimize the *stun* by exluding the guest memory from the snapshot. Including the memory requires to halt the machine until RAM contents are written to disk.

Comment: Yes it is working, but is there any data risk?

Comment: Well, RAM contents and the exact machine state aren't saved. If this is currently a problem you need to make sure the VM is 'nice' - back up databases before the snaphots, using logging, etc. The only other option is to buy faster storage...

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a significant IO overload. Which you can avoid with more ssd, less hard disks.